# HTML background-attachment: fixed. The background gets covered up after scrolling

Tags: html, css, background-image

I'm basically trying to create a background image whereby it will stay fixed in position forever. However, it seems that if the div internally has too much content and I scroll down, the image still does stay fixed but will become "covered" the more I scroll down.

[View at the very top of the page looks totally fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oSeAW.png)
[After scrolling down a little, the background starts to get covered (you can see the image is still fixed in position)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xGdBT.png)

Code snippet is as below. I've added loads of new lines in the inner div to show the problem

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Bootstrap 4 Example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <style>

        html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        }
        .bg{
        height: inherit;
        background-image: url("images/background.jpg");

        background-position: center center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
        background-attachment: fixed;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="bg">
    <div class="container">
    <h1>My First Bootstrap Page</h1>
    <p>This is some text.</p>
        <p>This is some text.</p>
        <p>This is some text.</p>
        <p>LOL</p>
        <p>This is some text.</p>
        <p>This is some text.</p>
        <p>This is some text.</p>
        <p>This is some text.</p>
        <p>This is some text.</p>
        <p>This is some text.</p>
        <p>This is some text.</p>
        <p>This is some text.</p>
        <p>This is some text.</p>
        <p>This is some text.</p>
        <p>This is some text.</p>
        <p>This is some text.</p>
        <p>This is some text.</p>
        <p>This is some text.</p>
        <p>This is some text.</p>
        <p>This is some text.</p>
        <p>This is some text.</p>
        <p>This is some text.</p>
        <p>This is some text.</p>
        <p>This is some text.</p>
        <p>This is some text.</p>
        <p>This is some text.</p>
        <p>This is some text.</p>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add `overflow:scroll;` to the `.bg` class

```css
bg {
    height: inherit;
    background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/200/300);
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    overflow:scroll; /* new selector added */
}
```

See the [Live preview](https://codepen.io/RammmohanBandaru/pen/ajGxGr)

Comment: thanks @Geek for the overflow selector! I'm using 'auto' now as it doesn't unnecessarily introduce a scrollbar

Comment: For every problem there may be lots of solutions, based on your requirement you can use any one of them

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `height 100%` in `html, body` and remove the `height: inherit;` in `.bg`. That should work.

Answer (score 0):

Check This Just give class "bg" to body instead of div

or just add

> overfloaw:scroll

in bg class

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Bootstrap 4 Example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <style>

        html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        }
        .bg{
        height: inherit;
        background-image: url("https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/378800000017423279/1a6d6f295da9f97bb576ff486ed81389_400x400.png");
       background-size: cover;
       background-attachment: fixed;
       background-position: right top;
   
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body class='bg'>
<div >
    <div class="container">
    <h1>My First Bootstrap Page</h1>
    <p>This is some text.</p>
        <p>This is some text.</p>
        <p>This is some text.</p>
        <p>LOL</p>
        <p>This is some text.</p>
        <p>This is some text.</p>
        <p>This is some text.</p>
        <p>This is some text.</p>
        <p>This is some text.</p>
        <p>This is some text.</p>
        <p>This is some text.</p>
        <p>This is some text.</p>
        <p>This is some text.</p>
        <p>This is some text.</p>
        <p>This is some text.</p>
        <p>This is some text.</p>
        <p>This is some text.</p>
        <p>This is some text.</p>
        <p>This is some text.</p>
        <p>This is some text.</p>
        <p>This is some text.</p>
        <p>This is some text.</p>
        <p>This is some text.</p>
        <p>This is some text.</p>
        <p>This is some text.</p>
        <p>This is some text.</p>
        <p>This is some text.</p>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Bootstrap 4 Example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <style>

        html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        }
        .bg{
        height: inherit;
        background-image: url("https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/378800000017423279/1a6d6f295da9f97bb576ff486ed81389_400x400.png");
       background-size: cover;
       background-attachment: fixed;
       background-position: right top;
       overflow:scroll;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body >
<div class='bg' >
    <div class="container">
    <h1>My First Bootstrap Page</h1>
    <p>This is some text.</p>
        <p>This is some text.</p>
        <p>This is some text.</p>
        <p>LOL</p>
        <p>This is some text.</p>
        <p>This is some text.</p>
        <p>This is some text.</p>
        <p>This is some text.</p>
        <p>This is some text.</p>
        <p>This is some text.</p>
        <p>This is some text.</p>
        <p>This is some text.</p>
        <p>This is some text.</p>
        <p>This is some text.</p>
        <p>This is some text.</p>
        <p>This is some text.</p>
        <p>This is some text.</p>
        <p>This is some text.</p>
        <p>This is some text.</p>
        <p>This is some text.</p>
        <p>This is some text.</p>
        <p>This is some text.</p>
        <p>This is some text.</p>
        <p>This is some text.</p>
        <p>This is some text.</p>
        <p>This is some text.</p>
        <p>This is some text.</p>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your background image to your body.

And Another solution is : Set overflow into your .bg Class `overflow-x:auto;`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Bootstrap 4 Example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <style>

        body{
        background-image: url("images/background.jpg");

        background-position: center center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
        background-attachment: fixed;
        }

        html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        }
        .bg{
        height: inherit;

        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="bg">
    <div class="container">
    <h1>My First Bootstrap Page</h1>
    <p>This is some text.</p>
        <p>This is some text.</p>
        <p>This is some text.</p>
        <p>LOL</p>
        <p>This is some text.</p>
        <p>This is some text.</p>
        <p>This is some text.</p>
        <p>This is some text.</p>
        <p>This is some text.</p>
        <p>This is some text.</p>
        <p>This is some text.</p>
        <p>This is some text.</p>
        <p>This is some text.</p>
        <p>This is some text.</p>
        <p>This is some text.</p>
        <p>This is some text.</p>
        <p>This is some text.</p>
        <p>This is some text.</p>
        <p>This is some text.</p>
        <p>This is some text.</p>
        <p>This is some text.</p>
        <p>This is some text.</p>
        <p>This is some text.</p>
        <p>This is some text.</p>
        <p>This is some text.</p>
        <p>This is some text.</p>
        <p>This is some text.</p>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```